# Docker Desktop for Windows: Cannot ping google.com from windows containers

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I was creating a container using `microsoft/windowsservercore` image. And then when I tried to ping google.com from inside the container, I got this error:

> Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name
>   and try again.

Then I switched to `Linux Container` mode in docker for windows. Then tried the same in an ubuntu container but this time it worked fine. Then when I switched back to `Windows Container` mode and tried the same thing again, it worked this time. Although my issue was resolved but I still don't understand what caused this issue in the first place ?

Comment: Another thing to try is to turn off your VPN if you're using one.

Answer (score 0):

Docker for windows and linux have different default network settings.
Typically, the default for linux is *bridged* mode while in windows you have *NAT*.

You can alter your configuration with [Network Connection Settings for windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itNrx.png)

See: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#network

The first option for me is always to look at the network section when executing `docker inspect *containername*`. This command gives you information about your network settings for the container. Other options are to check your firewall settings.

In general I usually use `ping 8.8.8.8` since *www.google.com* cannot be pinged even from my standard windows machine.